# Identify this bathroom extractor fan?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I have a bathroom extractor fan that has gone bad, so I need to replace it. If possible, I would like to just replace the motor, rather than opening up the ceiling to put in a whole new enclosure. The problem is, I don't know how to find a replacement. Here are a few pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The cover says "Nutone", but I can't get any hits by Googling the partial text visible on the back of the fan. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

NuTone likely doesn't have anything to do with this.  That is a newer NuTone fan cover that has been drilled to fit over the center post on what is a very old vent fan.  That vent fan used to have a round cover that likely broke at some point.

That whole unit needs to be replaced.  The fan and housing look over 50 years old - there's just no point in trying to mess with what you can buy new for $15.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old unit.  Based on the (apparent) metal blades, the color of the motor housing, and the design of the mount, I'd guess it's at least 30-40 years old.  I can't find the model number on any old resources for NuTone models.  To be honest, I'm not sure you're going to find anything online to help with anything that old.  Your best bet would be to try and take the motor in and see if you can match it.  That being said, it looks like the motor is floating on those four arms, with rubber bushings for noise isolation.  you might want to screw the motor back into the mount and see how much play they have.  If they're worn out, or contacting the mount in any way, replacing your motor won't fix your noise issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nutone brand they are still made, you may be able to revive it with a couple of drops of oil in each end worked into the bearings. I have done this many times over the years even a very light penetrating oil will work for a year most of the time but a couple of drops of motor oil any weight can last for years.
As far as identifying the motor without numbers we would have to go by measurements. I have taken ones I could not revive in to the store and matched the sizes of a new one with the dead one so the housing fit and no additional work was needed to replace the motor.